# Problems encountered in FB Like button functionality

Tags: javascript, iframe-app

I am using a fb like button on my site. But it just creates an activity in activity log. I want this to get shared with everyone in my friend list i.e. I want it to get posted on my wall.

How can I achieve this??

Any help will be highly appreciated..

Note: I just created a link for like using following URL: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/.

Please let me know If I have to anything additional.